# Django jquery .load function

Tags: jquery, django, load

I am trying to load a django url into a div using the jquery .load() function and no content is appearing in the div. I am pretty sure it is not loading at all because if I use firebug it shows no content.

Here is the load function being called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create").click(function(){
        $("#popupContact").load("/cookbook/createrecipe");
    });
});
```

here is my template:

```
//snip
    <div id="popupContact" class="popup">
        <a id="popupContactClose" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;">x</a>                        
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup">
    </div>  
//snip
```

here is the element with create id:

```
{% block footer %}
        <div id="create" style="cursor:pointer" >Create New Recipe</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The link /coookbook/createrecipe worked fine when it was being used in "a" link tag but when I tried to switch over to loading content it would no longer work

Thanks for any help

snackerfish

Comment: Where is the element with the `create` id?

Comment: i have added it to my question

Comment: What HTTP status doest FireBug show for ajax response? There can be a problem with CSRF verifying, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the jQuery code? Is it being reached?

Comment: i dont think the ajax is being loaded at all because I dont see any response in net -> xhr

Comment: i resolved the issue, I placed the javascript inside of my base.html and it works fine thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the javascript code from my template to my base.html template and it seemed to work fine

thank you

snackerfish